# Merging numpy arrays with different dimensions to give input to a neural network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have created four numpy arrays. They are of different dimensions. But I want to merge them such these features are encoded in the third dimension. The shape of my vectors is:

```
feature1 :  (42,)
feature2 :  (42, 5, 7, 4)
feature3 :  (42, 5, 7)
feature4 :  (42, 5, 7)
```

I have 42 examples/batches, and (5,7) of feature3 and feature4 are 2D alignments and feature2 is the one-hot encoding of size (5,7,4)

I want a final numpy array that encodes as four features in the third dimension so get something like (5,42,4). How can I create such a numpy array? Also feature2 has an additional dimension at the end. How can I take care of that? I was using np.concatenate but it doesn't account for different dimensions like I have:

```
newArray = np.concatenate((ref_count_sub, alt_count_sub), axis=2)
```

newArray is what I want to give to my convolution neural network. Insights would be appreciated. I am new to deep learning therefore, I apologise if it's a basic question.

Comment: You need to study the neural network to learn what it expects.  There isn't an obvious way of "merging" those arrays, at least not in `numpy` terms.  `concatenate` is quite picky about matching dimensions, so you can't blindly throw arrays at it and hope it does the thinking for you.

Comment: I am trying to give these four inputs separately to a multi-input neural network but I guess I was wondering if there is way to combine these numpy arrays in a data structure that could be given to a neural network?

Comment: @hpaulj I know that concatenate won't work here which is why I posed a question if it's even possible to combine such numpy arrays together. The reason I mention concatenate here is to give an idea what I am trying to achieve

Comment: I think the best option is to have a multi-input network. I you really ned to merge your array, you need to expand them to the larger shape (42,5,7,n) but I strongly advise you not to, as you would just duplicate data and it won't help the NN, but most likely hurt it.

Comment: @CoMartel. Yes I am doing a multi-input network. I have one more question. I want my model to predict frequencies. So for a given input I could either have A,G,C or T. And I want my model to tell me which letter will it along with frequencies. I am using mean squared error to get the frequency and it works but I want my model to give me corresponding letter as well. How can I do that? Will it be a multi-output?